# finding a serial number of a jpg file in linux terminal

Tags: ssh, syslinux, jpeg

I have issues decoding my jpg file to find it'sserial number from my linux terminal thought ssh . 
my file and detail of command I did
`M5KDAN44`

```
grep "serial number" M5KDAN44
```

my error serialnumber is a value and not a sting to find
please help

Comment: A `.jpg` file is usually an image in "JPEG" binary format (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format ), so `grep` is inappropriate. Also, what is the "serial number" of which you speak? The command you list searches for the text string "serial number" in the file called `M5KDAN44`.

Comment: @William Mollet Do you mean you have jpg files without the extension in the file name, e.g 123 in place of 123.jpg.

Comment: Do you mean meta-information inside the image? Something like `exiftool image.jpg | grep "serial number"`?

Comment: @Vijay yes that's right but i need to find it's serial number (SN)

Comment: @William Mollet I have edited the answer.

Comment: Where the serial number supposed to be ? In the filename or encodes into the picture itself ?

Comment: @William Mollet, may I  refer you to this page:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222610/view-images-over-active-linux-ssh-session  It has the answers to all you ask.

Answer (score 3):

**Change directory to the target directory**

```
cd /path/to/dir/with/files
```

**To find jpg (JPEG) files if the extension is removed.**

```
OIFS="$IFS";IFS=$'\n';for f in `find ./ -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \;|grep image/jpeg|cut -d ":" -f 1`;do echo "$f";done;IFS="$OIFS"
```

**For the Serial Number of the camera in EXIF data.**
The command is:

```
exiftool <file-name> | grep '^Serial Number'
```

**Example**

```
exiftool IMG_0277 | grep '^Serial Number'
Serial Number                   : 078073094979
```

**Both commands combined to find jpg (JPEG) files and get the Serial Number.**

```
OIFS="$IFS";IFS=$'\n';for f in `find ./ -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \;|grep image/jpeg | cut -d ":" -f 1`;do echo "$f" `file --mime-type "$f"|cut -d ":" -f 2` `exiftool "$f"|grep '^Serial'`;done;IFS="$OIFS"
```

**Example:**

```
OIFS="$IFS";IFS=$'\n';for f in `find ./ -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \;|grep image/jpeg | cut -d ":" -f 1`;do echo "$f" `file --mime-type "$f"|cut -d ":" -f 2` `exiftool "$f"|grep '^Serial'`;done;IFS="$OIFS"
./IMG_9862 07.JPG  image/jpeg Serial Number                   : 078073094979
./008  image/jpeg
./IMG_0277 06  image/jpeg Serial Number                   : 078073094979
./new folder/IMG_0277 06  image/jpeg Serial Number                   : 078073094979
./new folder/008 03  image/jpeg
./DSC04592 05  image/jpeg
./008 03  image/jpeg
```

**Note: Not all jpg files have 'Serial Number' in EXIF data.

The Serial Number of the camera is written by most newer DSLR cameras in EXIF data**